# Is there a way to tell Google Docs not to upload files that have already been uploaded?

Tags: google-drive

If I upload a file that already exists on Google Docs (because I didn't realize I already uploaded it, or because I'm doing a bulk upload) I get a second copy of the file.

Is there any way to get Google Docs to check for duplicates?

Answer (score 2):

There is no such option in Google Docs as such . But there may be possibility of using GreeseMonkey Scripts or third-party browser extensions for doing so.

But there the problem would be that we have to match the file-name and size of each newly uploaded file with all the existing once, but Google Docs does not shows the file sizes of individual files in anyway.

The third-party extension would have to download the all the files to make it possible - which is not practical and also not possible because Google Docs sometimes converts the uploaded files into it's own format - screws the formatting and file size also alters.

So, basically not possible.